# Trying to a save file in local folder in python

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
    home_dir = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)  
    stock_file_path = os.path.join(home_dir, 'data', 'stock_data.csv')
    stock_data.(stock_file_path, index=True)


    stock_data.(stock_file_path, index=True)
               ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Stock_data contains some data, taken from yahoo API, I want  save it in my local folder as csv file. It is showing Invalid Syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
stock_data.to_csv(stock_file_path, index=True)
```

You forgot the method name and I'm just going to assume you're using a Pandas DF from the context and params.

[docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

It should be so. You need to add `to_csv` after stock_data:

```
home_dir = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)  
stock_file_path = os.path.join(home_dir, 'data', 'stock_data.csv')
stock_data.to_csv(stock_file_path, index=True)
```